# Keep me logged in option in facebook desktop login flow not working

Tags: facebook, macos, facebook-graph-api, oauth, desktop-application

I must use facebook integration within desktop app on OSX. I've used part of facebook sdk for ios and modified all ui elements to properly work on desktop.

I'm presenting facebook dialogs within webView, display is set to **popup**, and redirect url is `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`.

Everything seems to work fine (all the dialogs are working after login, token and expiration date seems to be ok and are stored between web sessions) except for the facebook cookies which are always set to be session only (even with the keep me logged in option turned on). This means user has to log in to facebook everytime app is opened which is really frustrating.

I've already tried setting display to other values (touch, page) with no success. Probably all relevant settings in facebook app are checked (Native or desktop app?, Embedded Browser OAuth Login, Client OAuth Login).

so the question is if anyone has encountered same problem or might know the solution to make keep me logged in option working properly?

Comment: I think that is most likely not an issue of what parameters you are using for the login dialog, but rather one of using a WebView in the first place …

Comment: @CBroe could you say something more on why you think there`s problem with using WebView? Even on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm they are telling to embed WebView within app. Besides not all facebook cookies are set to session only, just these crucial to keep user logged in.

Comment: So you get some cookies that “survive” inside the webview between closing and opening the app again, but others don’t?

Comment: yes those with expiration date set are stored and do "survive" between app openings.